# strcmp call keeps crashing my program

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf, strcmp

I'm creating a "phonebook" program for school. Basically I have to get a user to input the names and phone numbers of their contacts into two different arrays. I got that part down, but after I have to give the user an option to search the contacts either via name or phone number and I'm running into some issues.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int arraysize;
    printf("How many phone numbers will you be entering: ");
    scanf("%d", &arraysize);

    int * phoneNumbers = malloc(arraysize);
    char * names = malloc(arraysize);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
    {
        printf("Please enter the name of person %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &names[i]);
        printf("Please enter %s's phone number: ", &names[i]);
        scanf("%d", &phoneNumbers[i]);
    }
    char * searchOption;

    printf("Would you like to seach via name or phone number? ");
    scanf("%s", &searchOption);

    if (strcmp(searchOption, "name") == 0)
    {
        char * searchName;
        int element;
        bool stop = false;
        while (stop = false)
        {
            searchName = NULL;
            printf("\nPlease enter the name you wish to search for: ");
            scanf("%s", &searchName);
            for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
            {
                if (strcmp(searchName, names[i]) == 0)
                {
                    element = i;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop = false)
            {
                printf("\nname not found, please search again!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure it's crashing at the strcmp() call but I have no idea why

Comment: `while (stop = false)` -- That's an assignment. It should be `while (stop == false)`.  Actually, no, it shouldn't; it should be `while (!stop)`. Same thing for the `if` near the end.

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? I imagine the compiler would have choice words for your use of `char *searchOption[256];`.

Comment: @EOF: Passing it to `strcmp` should have caused a warning (or a fatal error). Passing it to `scanf` is equally incorrect, but won't necessarily trigger a warning from an insufficiently clever compiler. (gcc is sufficiently clever).

Comment: You changed the code in your question in response to the answers, without mentioning that you changed it. **Please don't do that.** Originally you had `char * searchOption;`. You changed it to `char * searchOption[256];`, an array of 256 pointers. Don't try to "fix" the code in your question; doing so can invalidate both the question and the answers. I'm going to roll back your latest edit.

Comment: @EOF: The code was edited. I've rolled it back.

Comment: Not it's crashing at the string compare with names[i]. I've edited the program to include all the code because it's declared at the very begining

Comment: @zman419: `char *names` is *probably* not what you want (you certainly don't use it correctly). You want `char **names`, because every name is a separate string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in

```
scanf("%s", &searchOption);
```

you're doing it wrong.

You need to

- First allocate memory to `searchOption` pointer (or make it an array).
- pass `searchOption`, not `&searchOption` to `scanf()`.

Same issue appears for `char * searchName;` also later in the code.

Comment: Same for `scanf("%s", &searchName);`

Comment: @AlterMann Right. I stopped seeing the code after this. Let me update that too. :)

Comment: I did what you said, and it doesn't crash anymore, however when I enter "name" it doesn't enter the if statement, I'll update my code with what I have now

Comment: On POSIX systems, `%ms` with `&searchOption` would allocate the space for you.  But that's a tad advanced — not all systems support the notation.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is not directly caused by the `strcmp()` call.

This line is at fault:

```
scanf("%s", &searchOption);
```

First of all, there is a type mismatch. For `%s` you have to pass an argument of type `char*`, not `char**` as you did. To fix this, remove the take-address (`&`) operator.

Additionally, you need to allocate memory to scan into. The `scanf` function doesn't do that for you. As a quick and dirty fix, you can simply make `searchOption` an array. Replace its declaration with

```
char searchOption[100];
```

or such to fix this. You also want to limit the number of characters `scanf()` attempts to read:

```
scanf("%100s", searchOption);
```

so there can't be a buffer overflow.

An even better approach is to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. The `fgets()` function is suited better for what you want to do. Read the manual for how to use `fgets()`.

As Alter Mann said, the same problem occurs a second time further down. You need to repair that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Also i think in strcmp you have used "name" whereas you declared it as names before.If you correct this maybe program works